# audio playing from within python crashes due to msvcr90.dll exception

Tags: python, portaudio, pyaudio, msvcr90.dll

I wrote a program that uses pyaudio to record and play audio signal simultaneously.
for some unknown reason sometimes when playing signals the program crashes with this error:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x72A6AE7A (msvcr90.dll) in python.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x02F4DB94.
```

the program uses the libraries pygame, pyaudio, numpy

is there a way to understand where exactly is the problem ?
Thank you,
Netanel

Answer (score 0):

This is more a workaroud than a proper answer, but:
The problem ceased to exist when the signal was played by using the "blocking" mechanism of pyaudio, ie:
opening a stream something like:

```
stream = self.player.open(format = pyaudio.paFloat32, channels = 2, rate = FS, output = True, frames_per_buffer = CHUNK)
```

and then playing with something like:

```
while True:
    a = self.chunk_queue.get_nowait()
    self.stream.write(a)
```

the use of the non blocking mode play (by configuring a callback function for the stream) seems to have be the source for the crashes.